# Sharepoint app, missing styles and images when debug

Tags: sharepoint-addin, visual-studio, error, debugging

Trying to run a simple Sharepoint 2013 App in Visual Studio **(however, the same thing happens with all Sharepoint-store installed apps)**. I have set a url
`http://sharepointsrv/sites/devtest/` as the site to be used for debugging, (where devtest is a Developer Site) and to be SharePoint-hosted. Also in central administration, I have set `apps.sharepoint.demo.local` as App domain and `app` as App prefix in Configure App URLs page.

When pressing debug, my app opens in the browser but seems (see pic) like several images and styles are missing. Also the app url is quite big and strange:

```
http://app-32d8d8577b05ac.apps.sharepoint.demo.local/sites/devtest/MyWorld/Pages/Default.aspx?SPHostUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fsharepointsrv%2Fsites%2Fdevtest&SPLanguage=en-US&SPClientTag=0&SPProductNumber=15%2E0%2E4569%2E1000&SPAppWebUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fapp-32d8d8577b05ac%2Eapps%2Esharepoint%2Edemo%2Elocal%2Fsites%2Fdevtest%2FMyWorld
```

[image]

Comment: [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163816.aspx) explains the "weird" url a bit.  The domain, `app-weirdstuff.apps.sharepoint.demo.local`, gets generated each time the app is deployed.

Comment: I had similar problem and I created a blank web application on port 80 without any host headers and also added a blank port 80 binding to the web application I deployed the apps to.

Answer (score 0):

Try to view the HTML source of the app's page through your browser. Find the paths for your CSS, images etc and check that they are correct (such as by opening them in new browser tabs).

If you are using paths such as ../images/file.png then I suspect your folder structure and path levels are different between when you are debugging locally versus when you have deployed the app.

Comment: Same thing happens in all Sharepoint-store apps, so it's not about local paths. Also the images missing are not set by me, there on the sharepoint menus. Paths are like http://app-32d8d8577b05af.sharepoint.demo.local/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23